# How to parse xml from url link in kotlin, android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url, kotlin

I was trying to parse xml from an url link for example: http://a.cdn.searchspring.net/help/feeds/sample.xml , I can parse it from a file, but not from an url link. Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import org.w3c.dom.Element
import org.w3c.dom.Node
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import org.xml.sax.SAXException
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.URL
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var empDataHashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
        var empList: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()
        var url = URL("http://a.cdn.searchspring.net/help/feeds/sample.xml")

            val lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)

            // Using a background thread to do network code
            val thread = object : Thread() {
                override fun run() {
                    try {
                        // Comment-out this line of code
                        // val istream = assets.open("empdetail.xml")
                        val builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        val docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()
                        val doc = docBuilder.parse(InputSource(url.openStream()))
                        // reading player tags
                        val nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product")
                        for (i in 0 until nList.length) {
                            if (nList.item(0).nodeType.equals(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
                                empDataHashMap = HashMap()
                                val element = nList.item(i) as Element
                                empDataHashMap.put("name", getNodeValue("name", element))
                                empDataHashMap.put("id", getNodeValue("id", element))
                                empDataHashMap.put("brand", getNodeValue("brand", element))

                                empList.add(empDataHashMap)
                            }
                        }

                        val adapter = SimpleAdapter(
                                this@MainActivity,
                                empList,
                                R.layout.custom_list,
                                arrayOf("name", "id", "brand"),
                                intArrayOf(R.id.name, R.id.ratings, R.id.role)
                        )

                        runOnUiThread {
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter)
                        }
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: ParserConfigurationException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: SAXException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }

            thread.start()
        }


    //return node value
    public fun getNodeValue(tag: String, element: Element): String{
        val nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag)
        val node = nodeList.item(0)
        if(node != null){
            if(node.hasChildNodes()){
                val child = node.firstChild
                while(child!=null){
                    if(child.nodeType === org.w3c.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    {
                        return child.nodeValue
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

I am also added internet permission in menifest file. While I'm running the code, this code is running without any warning. But just an empty activity comes. No data is being showed there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used wrong way to get xml from url.
You should request data from the url.

Like this in java:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(target);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();
    }
```

And use this to get data in string:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
br.close();
return sb.toString();
```

Hope this could help.